# How to cache AAD B2C SecurityTokens in ASP.NET Core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

In ASP.NET API we where using a OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider that would cache the SecurityTokens for 1 minute before refreshing it again.

Is there a way to reproduce such behavior in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Have you solved this issue, do you need further assistance?

Answer (score 1):

I just used [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/) to check the `JwtBearerOptions` under my .NET Core 2.0 Web API. You could explicitly configure `JwtBearerOptions.ConfigurationManager` which is responsibe for retrieving, caching, and refreshing the configuration from metadata. Here is the code snippet, you could refer to it:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(jwtOptions =>
    {
        jwtOptions.Audience = "{Audience}";
        jwtOptions.Authority = "{Authority}";
        jwtOptions.ConfigurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
            "https://login.microsoftonline.com/bruceb2c.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={your-signin/signup-policy}",
            new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever())
            {
                RefreshInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0) //5 minutes
            };
    });

    services.AddMvc();
}
```